# Heroku Scheduler overlapping jobs

Tags: heroku, heroku-addon

I have a 6 jobs scheduled to be executed according with the next squema:

- :00
- :10
- :20
- :30
- :40
- :50

A job which started at :00 might take 15 minutes, so I don't want the task to be executed at :10 is executed but is in fact executed as the other are too, independently if there are task being executed, this create a new scheduler always.

I have the basic plan

I though to create in my python code a line to determinate if there is at least a scheduler running, don't do anything, but I don't know how to reach that into my python code.

I also though to avoid the creation of more than 1 scheduler through the Procfile like adding this `heroku ps:scale scheduler=1` but I didn't work.

### Edit

Finally I had to interact with a database in order to register there when a job is running. So basically, I created a table with 3 columns, started_at, finished_at, and status. Thanks to @ceejayoz by his help

Comment: My framework of choice, Laravel, has a `withoutOverlapping()` function in its scheduler. Behind the scenes, it's using something like Redis to make [a distributed lock](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/). Every invocation of the scheduler checks for the existence of a lock and cancels out if present. You could do this in a variety of ways (Redis isn't the only option, you could use a database or something).

Comment: I'm using django and maybe it has a way to do the same, however I don't know it. But the question is, how my code knows that there is a scheduler coming or a scheduler being executed

Comment: Your code would attempt to create a lock. If unable to generate a lock, this means another instance is still running, and should `return` or `exit` or whatever is appropriate instead of continuing. When your code finishes, it should release the lock.

Comment: What are you meaning with _create a lock_ ? AFAIK, Heroku Scheduler trigger the job  and the server receive it and execute it. How my code can detect that in order to create a lock?

Comment: You write your job so the very first thing it does is try to obtain a lock; I linked an article showing how to do that with Redis. You can't stop the scheduler from running the job, but you can stop the job from *doing* anything.

Comment: I had to use my database, so there I created a table with the record of my jobs and with a status column to control and avoid a duplicity